# How do you pin the menu in Azure portal?

Tags: azure

How do you pin open the left-hand side menu with the Azure services?

Mine always collapses so I have to start remembering what the different icons are so I can switch between services.

Comment: I always cringe when I'm forced to use a hamburger menu and click twice every time while a huge amount of screen real estate is unused.

Answer (score 12):

1. Select portal settings from gear icon on top right.
2. Under "Choose your default mode for the portal menu" select "Docked". This will
   pin the left hand menu

Comment: This is under the "Appearance + startup views" section as of today (31-AUG-2023).

Answer (score 2):

Far as I can tell, there is no way to make it stay open when you open something.

You can click the icon at the top-left corner with the three lines to make it re-appear at any time though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pin the left-hand side menu. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

What you could do is click on the expander (not sure if this is the right term) to expand the side menu. Will that work for you?

Comment: I currently use the expander, I was just hoping there was a way to pin it open. A colleague of mine says his menu is always expanded

Comment: Even I am seeing the same behavior as you're seeing. As soon as I open something up, side menu collapses.

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome with the Custom JavaScript Extension, which injects this script to portal.azure.com.

First, we extend the addClass method and trigger a custom event after (you could create a pre-event trigger also):

```js
(function(){ // Create a closure because good
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass; // reference original method to extend it
    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments ); // first execute the original method
        jQuery(this).trigger('cssClassChanged'); // second trigger a custom event we attach to in document.ready
        return result; // return the original result
    }
})();
```

This attaches to the document ready event and detects all changes to the sidebar main div via the custom event defined above. If the **fxs-sidebar-is-collapsed** class is added, it removes it.

```js
$(function(){ // document ready function
    var selector = '#web-container > div.fxs-portal-main > div.fxs-sidebar.fxs-trim-border';  // valid only for the new portal; subject to change
    $(selector).bind('cssClassChanged', function(){
        if ($(selector).hasClass('fxs-sidebar-is-collapsed')) {
            // remove the collapsed flag and set the min-width to ensure (this may need to be a percentage or vw)
            $(selector).removeClass('fxs-sidebar-is-collapsed');
            $(selector).attr('min-width', '226px');
        }
    });
});
```

Now, until Microsoft adds an obviously common-sense "pin" function, this is a workaround for Chrome (and any other browser that can inject custom JavaScript similar to CJS) to keep your sidebar open.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You nailed it. It really appalls me why Microsoft didn't thought of this user experience feature. It's very annoying for the menu to collapse. Thanks!

Comment: Fortunately, Microsoft came to their senses and the state now persists. Glad this code could help some folks back then! Also, disclaimer to all: I'm sure they've changed quite a bit of the DOM so my answer would likely no longer work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, click on the **settings** icon on the top and select **Docked** instead of **Flyout**, see screenshot:

[image]